# I keep getting an output of 0 for this loop. How do I fix it?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to split my data frame into 4 smaller data frames according to the vaccine used and the diagnosis.

Here is the loop I've been trying to use:

```
# Define loop
gene_of_interest <- '1'
vaccines <- c("A", "B")
diagnosis <- c("Sick", "Healthy")

for (v in vaccines)
{
  for (d in diagnosis)
  {
    # Filter data
    CDR3_post_challenge_plot_prep <- CDR3_post_challenge_plot_prep[CDR3_post_challenge_plot_prep$Vaccine == v & CDR3_post_challenge_plot_prep$Diagnosis == d & CDR3_post_challenge_plot_prep$gene == gene_of_interest ,]
    
  
    assign(paste0("IgH_CDR3_COI_", v, "_", d), CDR3_post_challenge_plot_prep)
  }
}
```

The only data frame with any observations outputted from this loop is the one that satisfies the first conditions, that is, "A_Sick". But I know there should be observations in the other 2 data frames.

Here is some of what the data frame looks like:

```
structure(list(gene = c("1", "1", "2", "3", 
                        "1", "1"), abundance = c(27L, 15L, 33L, 20L, 20L, 
                                                 69L), Timepoint2 = c("D0.12h", "D0.12h", "D0.12h", "D0.12h", 
                                                                      "D0.12h", "D0.12h"), Vaccine = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                 2L), .Label = c("Control", "B", "A"), class = "factor"), 
               Diagnosis = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Healthy", 
                                                                           "Sick", "UNKNOWN - Not Challenged", "UNKNOWN - Treated prior to meeting diagnostic criteria"
               ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                        "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I get 2 obs in `A_Healthy` and `B_Sick`. 0 obs in `B_Healthy` and `A_Sick`. That's the correct result based on your sample data. Is this what you were expecting?

Comment: Since I didn't share the complete data frame, what you are getting would make sense. But I don't even get observations in 2 groups, only 1. Did you use the loop I used above?

Comment: You defined the filtered database as the same name as your unfiltered database. Try using the name `df` for your original database, and `df2` for the filtered version. (unsolicited advice: use shorter names for objects--long names can make code unnecessarily verbose, which increases the likelihood of mistakes and simply takes longer to write.)

Comment: Thank you, that worked!